# mysql update doesn't work before using header() on php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code here, that will send a numeric value to the database.
PHP code:

```
<?php
$ctr =1
<form method = 'POST'>
$radio =$ctr;
<input type 'radio' name = '$radio[ctr]' />
$ctr++;
<input type ='submit' name='submit'>

</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
for($ctr=1; $ctr<$countme; $ctr++)
{
score++;
}
enter code here
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE `tblname` SET `score` = '".$score."' where number = '$number');
if ($insert){ header('Location:somefile.php');}
}
?>
```

Now the problem is, the update query seems not working, the `header()` to work but it insert `0` value to the database. i'd tried changing the `header()` to an `echo` statement and the database is updated with the right value.

What do you think is the problem? The code doesn't return any error. thanks in advance.

Comment: This is **NOT** php stuff... check your code... you're missing `<?php`, your `for` statement is bad and you do not execute your (mysql) query with `mysql_query()`. use some `error_reporting(E^ALL)` to see all that errors on your page..

Comment: `header` only works if you have **NO OUTPUT** on the page before calling the header.

Comment: ah, yes. sorry i forgot it `$result =mysql_query(" UPDATE..")` that is really the code.. I'd change it now. But it's still not working, i dunno why

Comment: @hjpotter92 actually the header works. The sql query is the having problem. i dunno why

Answer (score 1):

This is not correction, this is creation… Your `<?PHP?>` code should be at the top of the page, because `header()` will no output anything if something is already printed on the page.

Also, you're missing your `mysql_connect()`, are you aware of that? And finally, this is **not** secure php, be careful.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $score = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['radio'] as $id => $value) {
        $value == true and $score++;
    }

    // mysql_connect();
    $insert = mysql_query("UPDATE `tblname` SET `score` = '{$score}' where `number` = {$number}");

    if ( $insert ) {
        header('Location:somefile.php');
    } 
}
?>


<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="radio[]" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Actually the value of the radio button is from the database, that's why it is inside the php tag. Like what i've posted.

Comment: about the `mysql_connect` it was written on a separate file. by the way, what is the difference between `'".$score."'` and `'{$score}'`.

Comment: none, you can parse php variables using {$my_var} inside double quotes, it's just easier to read while debugging. `echo "var: $myvar";` is good, but `echo "var: {$myvar}";` is prettier. and finally you can parse arrays using this way: `echo "var: $myvar[0]"` isn't correct, but  `echo "var: {$myvar[0]}"` is.